# Zoom in selection on map

Tags: powerbi, reporting, tableau-desktop

I have a built a Dashboard with a map. I'd like to integrate a Zoom In selection, so that when I select a country, it shows it states and when I select the state, it shows the cities in that state and the amounts of entries in my case accordingly. Here's a screenshot of my map:

Behavior I would like:

1. Countries shown as a start
   [image: Countries]
2. User clicks on Germany and sees the states

[image: States]

3. User clicks on the state and sees the cities

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build that using this tutorial: [here](https://www.thedataschool.com.au/jaime-reyes/3-tier-map-drill-down-tutorial-using-set-actions-and-container/)

The method consists of playing with action filters and containers. I will not re-explain it, since the tutorial is really great.